# Can an unnamed parameter of function have a default value?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, default-parameters, function-signature

Is the following code legal in C++?

```
void f(void* = 0)
{}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

Which page of the C++ standard states that this usage is legal?

Comment: However it is, I cannot figure out in what contrived situation such a feature could actually have any use...

Comment: @MatteoItalia `enable_if` commonly.

Comment: And how giving the parameter a name would change the situation?

Comment: @MatteoItalia gives you unused variable warnings mostly.

Comment: @Pubby: `(void)parametername;`

Comment: @MatteoItalia: it wouldn't, but if you don't need a name, why giving one?

Comment: @MatteoItalia, One other "use" is if you have separate declarations and definitions and don't normally put the names in the declarations, but do put the default arguments in there.

Comment: BTW we tend to use "chapter and verse" to reference standard passages, rather than logical or physical page numbers.

Comment: This question was useful for 'inline' definitions of a base class that does nothing, but has default argument.  The derived class implementation uses the arguments.  Of course, the base could be pure virtual.  I think the compiler wouldn't give a diagnostic about the variable, in that case.  But I think it is useful stylistically to indicate  the parameter is unused.

Comment: This is useful when you have a parameterized method in an abstract class `class A { void foo(int); }`, but your implementation of that method doesn't care about the parameter `class C: A { void foo(int = 0) override { ... }`, so you can call your method without arguments without introducing another method `C c; c.foo();`. This isn't _that_ contrived is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes, it's legal.**

There is no standard wording to allow this combination of features specifically; there simply isn't any to *disallow* it, either.

Default argument syntax applies to function parameters in a *parameter-declaration*:

> `[C++11: 8.3.6/1]:` **If an *initializer-clause* is specified in a *parameter-declaration* this *initializer-clause* is used as a default argument.** Default arguments will be used in calls where trailing arguments are missing.

...and function parameters in a *parameter-declaration* may be unnamed:

> `[C++11: 8.3.5/11]:` *[..]* An identiﬁer can **optionally** be provided as a parameter name. *[..]*

There is even an example of this usage under 8.3.6/4 (though examples are not normative text, so this cannot be used to prove anything concretely).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it's perfectly legal. An obvious example is found in N3485 **8.3.6 Default Arguments**/4:

> [Example: the declaration
>
> ```
> void point(int = 3, int = 4);
> ```
>
> declares a function that can be called with zero, one, or two arguments of type int.

Comment: Examples aren't normative ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm looking :) It's not like it explicitly says "Default arguments can be unnamed." I imagine it goes off of the basis that it shares properties with non-defaulted parameters.

Comment: Okay, I got a confusing proof set up, but Light did a much better job of it, so it's not worth trying to confuse people who come later :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is legal.
The syntax productions given for function parameters in clause 8.3.5/1 allow a parameter declaration without an identifier, but with an assignment expression (as initialiser).

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it legal, it could actually be quite useful depending on your coding style.

Default parameters are only meaningful in a function declaration.

Named parameters are only meaningful in a function definition.

**f.h:**

```
void f(void*=nullptr);
```

**f.cc**

```
void f(void* x)
{
...
}
```

Comment: _"Named parameters are only meaningful in a function definition."_ lolwut.. I understand what you're trying to say here but I find it somewhat ludicrous.

Comment: Wouldn't `*=` be considered one token?